# Java8: Stream filter, map and joining with an alternative result if the stream is empty

Tags: java, stream, join

Given a list of integers, I would like to:

- filter odds numbers
- produce a list inside brackets: `[n1, n2, n3]`
- if the list is empty it should be a dash `-`

---

My current implementation is:

```
private static String doIt(List<Integer> list) {
    List<String> l = list.stream()
            .filter(i -> (i % 2 == 0))
            .map(Object::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    if (l.isEmpty()) {
        return "-";
    }
    return l.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.joining("; ", "[", "]"));
}
```

I am wondering if it is possible to do it without the intermediate list result `l`.

There is a problem with following implementation:

```
private static String doIt(List<Integer> list) {
    return list.stream()
            .filter(i -> (i % 2 == 0))
            .map(Object::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining("; ", "[", "]"));
}
```

The result in case of empty list is `[]` (expected is `-`)

---

Test method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(doIt(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)));
    System.out.println(doIt(Arrays.asList(2, 3, 4)));
    System.out.println(doIt(Arrays.asList(1, 3)));
}
```

Expected Result:

```
[2]
[2; 4]
-
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need this specific behavior?

Comment: I am generated some code (chained methods): `.collect(Collectors.joining(").chain(", ".chain(", ")"))` when there is no elements after filter, result should be `""` and not `"chain()"`

Comment: But I am wondering why. What is the context, what is the use-case?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `reduce`, it returns an `Optional` that is empty if the stream is empty. You can use `map` to create the csv (or reduce) and add the brackets and `orElse` to return "-".

```
private static String doIt(List<Integer> list) {
    return list.stream()
            .filter(i -> (i % 2 == 0))
            .map(Object::toString)
            .reduce((left, right)-> left+"; "+right)
            .map(csv -> "["+csv+"]")
            .orElse("-");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to still rely on `Collectors.joining` (and not implement that logic yourself), you can simply add a `.replace ("[]", "-")` to alter the output of the empty case.

```
private static String doIt(List<Integer> list) {
    return list.stream()
               .filter(i -> (i % 2 == 0))
               .map(Object::toString)
               .collect(Collectors.joining("; ", "[", "]"))
               .replace ("[]", "-");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of showing a different approach, and answering your tweet https://twitter.com/j2r2b/status/943163833975177216.
With a custom Collector and StringJoiner. You can convert the Integer to String in the same Collector and even apply some null check there if needed.
Tbh, if you need this feature a lot, you can create a class with a constructor that accepts all separator, prefix, suffix and defaultValue and reuse it. Otherwise, for a single use, I'd stick with one of the other options or the enunciate itself.

```
private static String doIt(List<Integer> list) {
    return list.stream()
        .filter(i -> (i % 2 == 0))
        .collect(new Collector<Integer, StringJoiner, String>() {

            @Override
            public Supplier<StringJoiner> supplier() {
                return () ->
                    new StringJoiner("; ", "[", "]")
                        .setEmptyValue("-");
            }

            @Override
            public BiConsumer<StringJoiner, Integer> accumulator() {
                return (joiner, val) -> joiner.add(val.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public BinaryOperator<StringJoiner> combiner() {
                return (joiner1, joiner2) -> joiner1.merge(joiner2);
            }

            @Override
            public Function<StringJoiner, String> finisher() {
                return joiner -> joiner.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
                return Collections.emptySet();
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Improving StringJoiner solution (that is way-more efficient than String concatenation):

```
private static String doIt(List<Integer> list) {
    return list.stream()
            .filter(i -> (i % 2 == 0))
            .map(Object::toString)
            .collect(Collector.of(
                    () -> new StringJoiner("; ", "[", "]").setEmptyValue("-"),
                    StringJoiner::add,
                    StringJoiner::merge,
                    StringJoiner::toString));
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].